# Android: Collapsing Linearlayout instead of Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to create a Master/Detail transaction in a single fragment. I thought of using LinearLayout as the container of my edittext for my header. Then a RecyclerView for details.

How would one implement the collapsing/expanding of LinearLayout similar to that of the CollapsingToolbar effect?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

My xml code so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_date_range_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/date_til"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Date">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:longClickable="false" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_store_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/store_til"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Store">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/store"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/location_til"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Location" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_car" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, not sure if this can be done with the CollapsingToolbar since I've mostly seen only ImageView collapsing in the Toolbar.

Appreaciate any help.

UPDATE: Basically what I want to do here is to be able to collapse the header view when scrolling up. Then expand when scrolling down.

Comment: update you xml file here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a timer and gradually shrink the height/margin of the topbar's LinearLayout (Edit: flaws in **Anton Maiorov's** answer is fixed here)

[image]

See below snippet (tested on devices)

Approach I: **Anton Maiorov's** answer, flaws fixed, this is much simpler than the 2nd implementation below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout toolbar;
    int mOriginalHeight;
    boolean initialSizeObtained = false;    
    boolean isShrink = false;

    Animation _hideAnimation = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
            params.topMargin = -(int) (mOriginalHeight * interpolatedTime);
            toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };

    Animation _showAnimation = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
            params.topMargin = (int) (mOriginalHeight * (interpolatedTime - 1));
            toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //Get the original height, which is measured according to WRAP_CONTENT
        toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (initialSizeObtained)
                    return;
                initialSizeObtained = true;
                mOriginalHeight = toolbar.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
        });
        _hideAnimation.setDuration(2000);
        _showAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    }

    //Click on the Olimpic image --> Toggles the top toolbar
    public void ToggleTopBar(View view) {
        isShrink = !isShrink;

        toolbar.clearAnimation();  //Important            
        toolbar.startAnimation(isShrink? _hideAnimation : _showAnimation);
    }
}
```

Approach II: my original answer by changing the toolbar's height, and also using timer manually, which is more involved:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout toolbar;
    int mOriginalHeight;
    boolean initialSizeObtained = false;
    int currentHeight;
    boolean isShrink = false;
    Timer timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (initialSizeObtained)
                    return;
                initialSizeObtained = true;
                mOriginalHeight = toolbar.getMeasuredHeight();
                currentHeight = mOriginalHeight;
                Log.d("Demo", "Original height is " + mOriginalHeight);
            }
        });
    }

    //Click on the Olimpic image --> Toggles the top toolbar
    public void ToggleTopBar(View view) {
        isShrink = !isShrink;
        Resize(isShrink, toolbar, 250);
    }


    void Resize(final boolean isShrink, final LinearLayout layout, final int minHeight) {
        final int H0 = mOriginalHeight;
        timer = runTimerAction(10, new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("demo", "Current Height= " + currentHeight);
                        if (isShrink && currentHeight > minHeight) {
                            currentHeight -= 10;
                            layout.getLayoutParams().height = currentHeight;
                            refreshToolbar();
                        } else if (!isShrink && currentHeight < H0) {
                            currentHeight += 10;
                            layout.getLayoutParams().height = currentHeight;
                            refreshToolbar();
                        } else {
                            layout.getLayoutParams().height = isShrink ? minHeight : H0;
                            refreshToolbar();
                            if (timer != null)
                                timer.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void refreshToolbar() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toolbar.requestLayout();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: How to call these animations during scroll?

Comment: I am able to understand the approach 1, but it looke like the animation is happening when we click on it, is it possible expand when we scroll up and collapse when we scroll down?

Answer (score 3):

Improved my answer using David's comment.

I would animate "topMargin" of your header:

```
LinearLayout _headerLayout; // expected to be set in "onCreateView"
int _headerHeight; // expected to be set in "onCreateView" as _headerHeight = getHeaderHeight();

Animation _hideAnimation = new Animation() {
  @Override
  protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) _headerLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.topMargin = -(int) (_headerHeight * interpolatedTime);
    _headerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
  }
};

Animation _showAnimation = new Animation() {
  @Override
  protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) _headerLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.topMargin = (int) (_headerHeight * (interpolatedTime - 1));
    _headerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
  }
};

private int getHeaderHeight()
{
  _headerLayout.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  return _headerLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

Hiding header:

```
_headerLayout.clearAnimation();
_headerLayout.startAnimation(_hideAnimation);
```

Showing header:

```
_headerLayout.clearAnimation();
_headerLayout.startAnimation(_showAnimation);
```

You can also easily set duration for your animations:

```
_hideAnimation.setDuration(2000) // will hide in 2 seconds
_showAnimation.setDuration(2000) // will show in 2 seconds
```

Comment: good answer, though some flaws. (1) You need to clear the animation before switching the animation; (2) params.height is always -2, since WRAP_CONTENT is used. I fixed these two in my answer. Anyway, upvoted!

Comment: @David concerning height, you are right, thank you. However I used startAnimation without clearAnimation fine before, you think this is an error?

Comment: I just tried that, without clear the animation, direct switching to another animation has no effect. No reason why, :)

Comment: @David Ok, I agree. It's safer with "clearAnimation" =)

Answer (score 2):

try this I added Coordinator and CollapsingToolbarLayput

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="15dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_date_range_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/date_til"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Date">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:longClickable="false" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_store_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/store_til"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Store">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/store"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/location_til"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Location" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_car"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />
```

I hope this should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [RIP's tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/19885/expand-and-collapse-animation-of-view), you can collapse or expand views using the snippet below.

```
public class ViewAnimationUtils {
        
        public static void expand(final View v) {
            v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    
            v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation a = new Animation()
            {
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                            ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                            : (int)(targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    v.requestLayout();
                }
    
                @Override
                public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
    
            a.setDuration((int)(targtetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
            v.startAnimation(a);
        }
    
        public static void collapse(final View v) {
            final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    
            Animation a = new Animation()
            {
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                    if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else{
                        v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                        v.requestLayout();
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
    
            a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
            v.startAnimation(a);
        }
    }
```

In addition, to specify the logic being applied to the animated view, in your case, it could be used a `ScrollListener` like

```
private fun RecyclerView.onViewScroll(title: String): OnScrollListener {
    return object : OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, state: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, state)
            rootView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.views_menu_header).let { layout ->
                if(state == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {                     
                    collapse(layout)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then, attaching the listener to your recycler

```
findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.views_menu_items).apply { addOnScrollListener(onViewScroll(title)) }
```

would collapse `R.id.views_menu_header` whenever the `R.id.views_menu_items` starts being dragged.