# How to pin linearlayout below toolbar while scrolling

Tags: java, android

I want to achieve something like the image shown below

[image]

I would like to paste a linearlayout under the toolbar and make it appear at a given moment during the scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can try this layout

**Original Layout**

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
         .
         .

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you but I want to put a layout in the middle of the scrollview (linearlayout or relativelayout or button) at the top of the scrollview when scroll

Answer (score 0):

You may use collapsing toolbar or customize according to needs.

Refer links below.

- [Android: Collapsing Linearlayout instead of Collapsing Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137188/android-collapsing-linearlayout-instead-of-collapsing-toolbar)
- https://medium.com/@martinomburajr/android-design-collapsing-toolbar-scrollflags-e1d8a05dcb02
- https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example
- http://www.zoftino.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout-example

Comment: thank you but I want to put a layout in the middle of the scrollview (linearlayout or relativelayout or button) at the top of the scrollview when scroll

Answer (score 0):

Check this, I've added comments in code for your items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <!-- YOUR ITEMS BETWEEN TABBAR AND APPBAR-->

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- YOUR CUSTOM TABBAR-->

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <!-- YOU MAIN CONTENT-->

                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>     
</RelativeLayout>
```