# How to expand layout when scrolling in Android?

Tags: java, android

Now I want to create layout like this [in my MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pXVm.png)

and I want to set up my scroll view. When I scrolling Content view move to top of Main view like this
[It move to Top of main view and expand content view follow my scroll view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X61NY.png)

and when it expanded reach the specified point I want to make it like this 
[set the top layout of content view (Red color) to fix not moving and go to scroll only main content layout (Blue Green Orange color)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbOTk.png)

and then finish of scrolling when i scroll down it all of layout return to [first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrKwL.png)

Anyone can help recommend me.

I have been stuck in this problem for many days.

**Java, Android Studio**

**I'm sorry for my English I'm not good at English**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Collapsing Linearlayout instead of Collapsing Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137188/android-collapsing-linearlayout-instead-of-collapsing-toolbar)